# submenu is hidden by other divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with a vertical submenu.

This site has a vertical menu fixed and a submenu that display besides it. But this submenu display below others divs. This is my current code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

  <div id="header-wrapper">
    <nav></nav>
  </div>

  <div id="masonry-content-wrapper">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header-wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}

#masonry-content-wrapper {
  padding: 0 2% 0 3%;
  margin-left: 250px;
}
```

It looks like the problem is that masonry div is not floating, but it is necesary for doing header width fixed. How can I solve it? This is the link http://www.codetocode-developments.com/personal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `#header-wrapper` to a `z-index` higher than 1. Like:

```
#header-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

Not exactly sure why Chrome needs it. Your original code works fine in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add z-index to header-wrapper

```
#header-wrapper {
    z-index:1000;
}
```

Fixes it.